# Updating editor.selections in vscode Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently working on a small vscode extension. Within the extension code I want to move every selection of a multi selection one character to the right by accordingly updating the `TextEditor.selections` array that holds all selections that are currently present in the GUI.

Setting `TextEditor.selection` to a new `vscode.Selection` allows updating the primary selection of the `TextEditor.selections` array. This way, the primary selection in the GUI is updated correctly. However, setting `TextEditor.selections[n]` to a new selection does not result in an update in the GUI. Hence, I can currently only update the primary selection instead of all of them. It seems like setting the shorthand `TextEditor.selection` issues a GUI update whereas setting `TextEditor.selections[n]` does not.

So, how can I update all selections in `TextEditor.selections`?

Here is my code for updating the selections:

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";

function updateSelections(
  editor: vscode.TextEditor,
  selections: vscode.Selection[]
) {
  selections.forEach((sel) => {
    const selStart = sel.start;
    const selEnd = sel.end;

    // TODO: only primary selection appears to be editable ; "editor.selections[n] = something" does not change anything
    // This works
    editor.selection = new vscode.Selection(
      selStart.translate(0, 1),
      selEnd.translate(0, 1)
    );
    // This does not work
    editor.selections[0] = new vscode.Selection(
      selStart.translate(0, 1),
      selEnd.translate(0, 1)
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign a new Array with the updated selections it works

```
editor.selections = editor.selections.map( sel => new vscode.Selection(sel.start.translate(0,1), sel.end.translate(0,1)));
```

Comment: this does work, for some reason the docs says editor.selections is read-only ! https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor.selections